# Why would I want to use reference to const in Constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

A bit silly question but Why?

Why would I want to use reference to const string, instead of just declaring a local string in Constructor?

```
class Person (const string &first_name, const string &last_name);
class Person (string first_name, string last_name);
```

Am I getting a reference to an automatic variable that way? o_O

Thank you!

Comment: Well it is less code.  It really depends on the use case though.

Comment: It is no different from  passing arguments via reference as compared  to passing arguments by value to a general function,  and there is no shortage of information on this topic.

Comment: If `first_name` and `last_name` are to be stored in the object, then I prefer the second (i.e the *non-const non-ref*) version *because* it is *efficient* while simplifying the code. That sounds counter-intuitive, but if you think carefully, you'll find it is indeed *efficient* and at the same time, it simplifies the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the semantics of what happens "behind the scenes" are quite different.

```
class Person1 {
    std::string f_name, l_name;
public:
    Person(std::string first_name, std::string last_name) :
    f_name(first_name), l_name(last_name) {
    }
};

class Person2 {
    std::string f_name, l_name;
public:
    Person(const std::string & first_name, const std::string & last_name) :
    f_name(first_name), l_name(last_name) {
    }
};
```

When you construct an instance of `Person1`, the names used to initialize it get copied twice: first to initiate local variables in the constructor, and second to copy-construct to the member variables. With `Person2`, however, only one copy happens: when the copy-construct to the member variables occurs.

With a trivial example like this, it might not be clear that this represents significant performance and memory implications, but for more complex programs, this can be quite significant.

Comment: If you use st::move in variable assignment in Person1, they will have almost same cost (Person1 and Person2)

Comment: @Amadeus True, but the cost of a Copy-Construct->Move-Assign is probably still greater than the cost of a Copy-Construct.

Comment: There is 3rd scenario when member variables are const references by themselves. They can be used by class instance for different purposes (watch list, etc.) without possibility to change them, but original strings referred by them can theoretically be changed during live time of the instance

Comment: "copied twice", not necessarily if an rvalue is used as argument and the copy gets elided.

Comment: @juanchopanza Provided the object is of a type that can be copy-elided by the compiler. Obviously the case with `std::string`, but may not be true for other object types.

Comment: @Xirema The rules for copy elision don't have much to do with the type.